# How do I make tabs changeable when using UI library?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, tabs

I am attempting to add some tabs to my content. I found the tabs control in the UI library and thought they'd be ideal. Unfortunately, they do not work. The tabs cannot be changed from one to another. In fact, even the [tabs in the UI library docs don't work properly either](https://magento-devdocs.github.io/magento2-ui-library/sections.html) so I don't think its something I'm doing wrong.

Am I missing something or do the UI library tabs not work properly?

Answer (score 0):

For render UI Componunt grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <insertListing>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">event_record_list</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</insertListing>
```